# Suppressing vertical space between environments

Tags: environments

I specified two environment in a LaTeX document to highlight different lines of codes:

```
\newenvironment{code}{\color{blue}}{\ttfamily}{\par}
\newenvironment{codegrey}{\color{grey}}{\ttfamily}{\par}
```

In the document, I want the latter one appear right below the first one without any spacing. Here are the codes:

```
\begin{code}
\begin{verbatim}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\end{verbatim}
\end{code}
\begin{codegrey}
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{3cm}llcp{5cm}|}
\end{verbatim}
\end{codegrey}
```

My goal is to display them as:
[image]
Instead of this:
[image]
Any suggestions are appreciated! This is my first time using newenvironment command and I find it really powerful.

Comment: I think the problem is from the verticle space caused by using the verbatim environment, not using \newenvironment itself. Any solution to this?

Comment: How about an alternative suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a shorter version using `fancyvrb`. You need not use separate environments for changing colours here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
  \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=+\[\],fontsize=\footnotesize]
+color[blue]\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
+color[gray]\begin{tabular}{|c|p{3cm}llcp{5cm}|}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use  `listings` package which offers `escapechar` key to enable the latex commands inside the verbatim atmosphere.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a \vspace with negative value in between like so:

```
\begin{code}
\begin{verbatim}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\end{verbatim}
\end{code}

\vspace{-3mm} %negative \vspace
\begin{codegrey}
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{3cm}llcp{5cm}|}
\end{verbatim}
\end{codegrey}
```

Edit: alternative is to add the negative vspace in the environment--

```
\newenvironment{code}{\color{blue}}{\ttfamily \vspace{-3mm}}
\newenvironment{codegrey}{\color{grey}}{\ttfamily \vspace{-3mm}}
```

but note that this will affect the spacing on the next paragraph after closing the environment

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,listings,etextools}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,mathescape,columns=fullflexible}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
$\AfterGroup{\color{blue}}$\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
$\AfterGroup{\color{gray}}$\begin{tabular}{|c|p{3cm}llcp{5cm}|}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Without [`etextools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etextools) you can use

```
\newcommand{\colorblue}{\color{blue}}
\newcommand{\colorgray}{\color{gray}}

...

\begin{lstlisting}
$\aftergroup\colorblue$\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
$\aftergroup\colorgray$\begin{tabular}{|c|p{3cm}llcp{5cm}|}
\end{lstlisting}
```